# Calcular días transcurridos entre columna de fechas y la fecha actual

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date

He visto por aquí que alguien ha hecho una pregunta semejante, pero no sé como aplicarlo en mi caso. 
Tengo un DF que contiene una columna que es `Fecha_inicio`. En esta columna aparece la fecha de creación de perfiles de usuario.

Sé que tengo que importar `pandas`, `numpy` y `datetime`.

Lo que necesito es saber cuántos días han transcurrido desde la fecha de creación hasta el día de hoy. Tener una columna que me diga, en cada fila, los días transcurridos. No importa si hay años bisiestos o no, no es problema. Las horas, minutos y segundos me dan igual también.

Mi columna es de tipo `object` y las fechas tienen la siguiente estructura:

> 2019-02-17 00:00:00

Debo recurrir a `date.today()` para conocer la fecha de hoy, pero no sé como proceder para obtener una columna que me diga los días transcurridos entre la columna `Fecha_inicio` y la fecha definida en `date.today()`.

Sé que la respuesta es simple, pero estoy entrando en bucle y no avanzo.

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, es un objeto. Te muestro un ejemplo: 2019-02-17 00:00:00 ((Las horas, minutos y segundos me dan igual)). Muchas gracias y un saludo,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conseguir la diferencia en días de cada  fecha hasta el día de hoy necesitas solo seguir una serie de pasos:

- Tu columna `Fecha_inicial` debe ser de tipo `Datetime` para poder operar cómodamente con fechas. Dependiendo de dónde vengan tus datos originales, puedes hacer esto al cargar el DataFrame directamente. Si lo anterior no es posible y tu columna es de tipo `str` (`object`), debes usar [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) para convertirla.

  Es importante especificar el formato correcto, de acuerdo al de la cadena que representa la fecha. En este caso el formato es:

  > "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

  para más información ver:

  - [Python Doc. strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)
- Obtener la fecha actual, lo cual se puede conseguir con [`pd.datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now).
- Restar a la fecha actual la columna de forma vectorizada. Esto resultará en una columna de `TimeDelta`.
- Para obtener solo los días basta con extraerlos mediante el atributo [`pandas.Series.dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html).

Un ejemplo completo reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Fecha_inicio": ("2019-02-17 00:00:00",
                                    "2019-05-27 00:00:00",
                                    "2019-09-07 00:00:00",
                                    "2019-12-23 00:00:00",
                                    "2020-01-15 00:00:00",
                                    "2020-02-20 00:00:00",
                                    "2020-03-01 00:00:00",
                                    )})

df["Fecha_inicio"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Fecha_inicio"],
                                    format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
                                    )

today = pd.datetime.now()
df["Días_transcurridos"] = (today - df["Fecha_inicio"]).dt.days
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>   Fecha_inicio  Días_transcurridos
> 0   2019-02-17                 379
> 1   2019-05-27                 280
> 2   2019-09-07                 177
> 3   2019-12-23                  70
> 4   2020-01-15                  47
> 5   2020-02-20                  11
> 6   2020-03-01                   1
> ```
>
> **Nota:** puedes proporcionar una `TimeZone` a `datetime.now` si lo requirieras.

Comment: FJSevilla, muchas gracias. Respuesta clara y limpia. Lo he probado y funciona perfectamente. Gracias gracias!!